# Open popup when item in listbox IsSelected

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have the following code to list images in a listbox. Currently I have a mouseover event that displays a popup upon IsMouseOver. I'm trying to figure out how to change this into IsSelected, but that does not exist in the current context. Is there a way to change the binding so that the popup opens when the item is selected? I've tried to do this from code-behind (SelectionChanged), but I'm not able to target the popup.

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Fisk}" x:Name="listy" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Margin="40,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" KeyDown="listy_KeyDown" Loaded="listy_Loaded" SelectionChanged="listy_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <vwp:VirtualizingWrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="item">
                <Image Width="250" ToolTipService.Placement="Center">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" CreateOptions="DelayCreation" CacheOption="None" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
                    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=item,Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay}" Placement="Center">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4">
                            <Image Width="280" ToolTipService.Placement="Center">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" CreateOptions="DelayCreation" CacheOption="None" />
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `RelativeSource` binding like this:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem},
                                        Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"
       Placement="Center">
    <!-- ... -->
</Popup>
```

Comment: That seems to work while inside the visible view, but if I scroll down and it's supposed to load more images I get the following exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: @NeoID the error you've just mentioned is not related to the answer. seems like you may need to look into the implementation of `vwp:VirtualizingWrapPanel`